# Need to extract substring from string surrounded by special character in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA,I have a string **I_HEAD_FOR**
I wanted to extract the substring which is started and ended by special character '_'(Underscore) in VBA.
I need code snippet which can do above task,Could you please help me with it
Here in this case The code should extract substring **HEAD**

---

This the idea is from:
**I_HEAD_FOR**

to get as a result:   **HEAD**

Comment: Look into split.  split on the `_` and take the result of position `1`:

Comment: Debug.Print Split("I_HEAD_FOR", "_")(1)

Comment: Thank you storex!! It works perfectly well.

Comment: Why my question gets voted down, Is there any issue with my Question.

Comment: Yes, because you did not show any effort on your own and you just wrote " I need code snippet " but this is not a code writing service

Comment: May be I have to describe what I have tried and tested to do better.@Storex  Thank you for quick help

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Public Function UnderScore(s As String) As String
    UnderScore = Split(s, "_")(1)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Gary's Student !!! You save my day :-)

Comment: @CodeNinja  You ae quite welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Excel, without VBA, this is the way you should think to make the formula:

- On which position is the first `_` sign?
- Knowing the first position of the first sign, can I find the second `_` sign?
- Now, knowing the first and the second position, is there a way to extract only the string, which is between the two positions?
- How can I unite the whole party into one formula, without getting crazy?

[image]

The Formulas `SEARCH` and `MID` together are pretty powerful. The `SEARCH` formula has optional value, saying where should you start search (see the second formula). Thus, we add `+1` to the first found value. In the second formula, the `-1` is added, because we do not want the position of the `_`, but the position before.

The formulas in text:

```
=SEARCH("_",A1,1)
=SEARCH("_",A1,SEARCH("_",A1,1)+1)-1
=MID(A1,B1+1,B2-B1)
=MID(A1,SEARCH("_",A1,1)+1,SEARCH("_",A1,SEARCH("_",A1,1)+1)-1-SEARCH("_",A1,1))
```

Comment: Or `TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",REPT(" ",10000)),10000,10000))`, which is slightly easier to turn into a general form for the `n`th item in the deliminated string (The second `10000` becomes `(n-1)*10000`)

Comment: @Chronocidal - impressive - it works and it is smaller :)